Why does querying for a post with -2000 votes return one with -1?
https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=score%3a..-2000, for a reason unbeknownst to me, returns solely How is it possible that "I" (the user Krumelur) exists twice?, which has -1 score.
I'm surprised by this, because, as an example, https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=score%3a..-1500 functions correctly, returning Update: an agreement with Monica Cellio.

Curious that it only happens for -2000, when -2001 and -1999 both work fine.

I think that reason for this is because it (for some reason) searching for the keywords "score", "...", "-", and "2000" somewhere in the text, which that post has. This also occurs for -100, -200, -500, and -1000 (didn't work at the time I tried it, now working as normal) amongst others for the same reason.

Other related bug reports. It seems that if you use a special operator (e.g. filter by date, votes, status), and no posts match the advanced search, the engine falls back to using each token separately, completely ignoring the operator. However, that's only a theory - this only gets reported in its individual manifestations.

@Starship On which site did you try "score:..-1000". Here on MSE, the following returns three posts: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A..-1000 which is what would be expected

@PeterJames at the time I tried it wasn't working here, it's clearly changed.
